# Move Tablestorage to BlobStorage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

is there any way of moving a table from the Tablestorage into the Blob Storage?
I thought of writing each line into a csv file. But is that really the fastest way?

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way would be to download the data from Azure Table through Query Entities locally, then write back the data in any form you need against Blob Storage; that could be CSV, some binary format, JSON, etc..
Azure Storage does not provide any Copy or backup functionality from AzureTable to AzureBlob. It is an already requested feature but we don't have any timeline to share.

Thanks,
Jean